# Lista com display inline não funciona corretamente

Tags: html5, css3

Preciso alinhar em 3 colunas as minhas imagem e textos me ajudem por favor segue o meu código eles estão em uma lista

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.corpo-1 h1 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 40%;
}
.corpo-1 p {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -2%;
}
.linha-titulo {
  width: 30%;
  height: 1.9px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
}
.tamanho {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
.info h1 {
  margin-top: -3%;
}
.info {
  text-align: center;
}
.info li {
  display: inline;
}
.info li img {}
```

```html
<section class="corpo-1">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor adipiscing<br />
            amet dolor consequat</h1>

  <p>Adipiscing a commodo ante nunc accumsan interdum mi ante adipiscing. A nunc lobortis non nisl amet vis volutpat aclacus nascetur ac non.
    <br/>Lorem curae eu ante amet sapien in tempus ac. Adipiscing id accumsan adipiscing ipsum.</p>

  <hr class="linha-titulo">
  <!-- <img src="images/logo-transp.png" /> -->
  <ul class="info">
    <li>
      <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/menami_sama/32531158/565942/565942_original.png" alt="" class="tamanho" />
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum at purus sed erat suscipit.</p>
      <p>Cras facilisis viverra wisi. Class sociosqu...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/menami_sama/32531158/565942/565942_original.png" alt="" class="tamanho" />
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum at purus sed erat suscipit.</p>
      <p>Cras facilisis viverra wisi. Class sociosqu...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/menami_sama/32531158/565942/565942_original.png" alt="" class="tamanho" />
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum at purus sed erat suscipit.</p>
      <p>Cras facilisis viverra wisi. Class sociosqu...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

eles tem que ficar assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui esta as imagem do meu botão como ficou nos navegadores apos as edições:

no Google chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No mozila:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no Safari:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no Opera:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código do botão:

```
 <p class="text-center">    
      <a href="#">
         <button id="btn-info">leia mais ...</button>
     </a>
 </p>

#btn-info{
    border:3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Gabriola;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5%;
    clear: both;

}

#btn-info:hover{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
.info li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

[Exemplo testado em todos navegadores](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/58umv0fq/2/)

Comment: amigo ultilizei su metodo e deu certo porem logo abaixo da minha lista vai um botao  que fica no centro so que ele fica certinhono google chrome e no opera  ja no mozila e no safari nao porque ele fica alinhado a esquerda da minha lista sabe oque houve

Comment: Como esta o code desse botão? (html e css)

Comment: vou editar o post para vc ver e colocar as imagem de como ele ficou nos navegadores

Comment: Amigo pronto editei ve se consegue compreender como vc pode ver nas imagem somente no chrome e no opera o botao ficou do jeito certo

Comment: O botão fica dentro da section?

Comment: isso fica dentro dele logo acima da tag </section>

Comment: Irmão, pq colocou <button></button> dentro da tag  <a href=""></a>?

Comment: putz vacilo e costume rsrsrs eu acabei de retirara porem nao mudou em nada a situacao

Comment: Ok, vc vai usar o <a> ou o <button> ?

Comment: Vou usar o o button q ele vai me redirecionar para outra pagina

Comment: Editei minha resposta, acesse o JSFiddle

Comment: vc e foda cara vlw mesmo

Comment: Valew irmão, sorte ai nos projetos!

Answer (score 1):

Para ficarem lado a lado você pode definir:

```
ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  float:left;
}
```

Ainda assim não teria um resultado como deseja, pois não estariam centralizadas, mas então basta definir uma largura para o seu `ul` e centralizar ele:

```
ul { 
  width:72%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Pode não ser a "melhor prática", mas funciona! :D

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
 }
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.corpo-1 h1 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 40%;
}
.corpo-1 p {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -2%;
}
.linha-titulo {
  width: 30%;
  height: 1.9px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
}
.tamanho {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
.info h1 {
  margin-top: -3%;
}
.info {
  text-align: center;
}
.info li {
  display: inline;
}
.info li img {}
```

```html
<section class="corpo-1">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor adipiscing<br />
            amet dolor consequat</h1>

  <p>Adipiscing a commodo ante nunc accumsan interdum mi ante adipiscing. A nunc lobortis non nisl amet vis volutpat aclacus nascetur ac non.
    <br/>Lorem curae eu ante amet sapien in tempus ac. Adipiscing id accumsan adipiscing ipsum.</p>

  <hr class="linha-titulo">
  <!-- <img src="images/logo-transp.png" /> -->
  <ul class="info">
    <li>
      <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/menami_sama/32531158/565942/565942_original.png" alt="" class="tamanho" />
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum at purus sed erat suscipit.</p>
      <p>Cras facilisis viverra wisi. Class sociosqu...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/menami_sama/32531158/565942/565942_original.png" alt="" class="tamanho" />
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum at purus sed erat suscipit.</p>
      <p>Cras facilisis viverra wisi. Class sociosqu...</p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/menami_sama/32531158/565942/565942_original.png" alt="" class="tamanho" />
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer elit.</p>
      <p>Vestibulum at purus sed erat suscipit.</p>
      <p>Cras facilisis viverra wisi. Class sociosqu...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Eu apenas disse que o UL  deveria centrar os seus LI's.
Faltava dizer display iria ter o UL.
ul{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
 }